# how to project a low pca dimension point back to original pca space in matlab

Tags: matlab, pca, projection

I have a 455 samples by 30 features matrix `X`. I am using the following pca projection into 2D:

```
[coeff, score, ~, ~, ~, mu]=pca(X');
gscatter(score(:,1),score(:,2),Y,'br','.');
```

Where `Y` are lables of the 455 samples.

Assuming I have a set of new 2D points `z` n samples by 2, which I want to project back to the 30d dimention, can I use `coeff` to project it? Is the following valid:

```
projecte30dz=z*coeff(1:2,:);
```

How do I project a new point in the low pca dimension back to the original space?

Comment: You need to transpose your eigenvector matrix and know the mean. Have a quick google there are a lot of answers ;)

Comment: You can't directly. Think about this way, when you go from 30d to 2d, you are basically looking for the two directions with the largest variance, but in the general case, there is still going to be variance on the other 28d, if you only have this two coordinates, then you are missing the information of the other 28d. That been said, you could estimate them or just assume them as zero in very specific cases, if your problem allows it.

Comment: @NoelSeguraMeraz granted, you cant fully restore but you can estimate. Surely you can mathematically project.  The projection represent an estimation. I have found a solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)

Comment: It's not estimating the other lost dimensions, it's assuming them to be zero, that's why in that example the reconstructed data is still a line (a one dimensional space). Yes, it is semantics, but it depends on what are you doing